# Inproduct and norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Search for a representation of a line that goes through a point $p$ and that is orthogonal with the plane $\alpha$.

$p=\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ 5\end{bmatrix}, \alpha =\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix} + \rho\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} + \tau \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 5 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}$

How do I this? I tried to convert $\alpha$ to a cartesian equation and then reverse the signs of each coefficient of that equation and cycle the variable with those coefficients but to no avail. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vectors $$\mathbf{v}_1=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\2\\2\end{matrix}\right)\;\;\;\;\mathbf{v}_2=\left(\begin{matrix}5\\5\\6\end{matrix}\right)$$ are the generator of the plane. To be perpendicular to this plane you have to find a third vector perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$. Obviously if you take the vector product of this to you are assured to find a perpendicular vector, so $$\mathbf{v}_1\times\mathbf{v}_2 = \det\left(\begin{matrix}\hat{i}&\hat{j}&\hat{k}\\1&2&2\\5&5&6\end{matrix}\right) = 2\hat{i}+4\hat{j} -5\hat{k}$$ The third perpendicular vector is, then $$\mathbf{v}_3 = \left(\begin{matrix}2\\4\\-5\end{matrix}\right)$$
Which is the **characteristic** vector of the plane. This will be the generator of our line. The parametric equation of a line with a certain generator vector passing through a point $P(x_p,y_p,z_p)$ is $$\left\{\begin{matrix}x = x_p+v_1t\\y=y_p+v_2t\\z=z_p+v_3t\end{matrix}\right.$$
so, in our case:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}x = 3+2t\\y=4t\\z=5-5t\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: Oh, of course. I was looking for the method in my previous worksheets, now I know where it is. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward solution is to simply construct the vector perpendicular to the plane as the cross product of your two planar vectors $(1,2,2)^t$ and $(5,5,6)^t$ (possible only in 3D). The line $l$ you're looking for would then be simply be represented by the point $p$ plus the orthogonal vector you just constructed.

Spelled out: 
$$l=\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ 5\end{bmatrix}+\lambda \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 5 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ 5\end{bmatrix}+\lambda \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ -5\end{bmatrix}$$
with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the characteristic vector of the plane is the cross product of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 5\\ 5 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}$ (this is because any point of the plane is a linear combination of these two vectors) which is $$\begin{bmatrix} 2\\4\\-5\\\end{bmatrix}$$therefore the line is$$\dfrac{x-3}{2}=\dfrac{y}{4}=\dfrac{5-z}{5}$$